# How to design a data table to hold multiple user with days of the current month and display it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, ssms, aspxgridview

I cant transpose my table the way I want it. I have for example 4 users some other data for them in the column. I have a dates table and these are connected to each other via a connection table. For example for

```
1 user1 date1 status
2 user1 date2 status
3 user1 date3 status
4 user2 date1 status
5 user2 date2 status
6 user2 date3 status
7 user3 date1 status
8 user3 date2 status
9 user3 date3 status
```

I want my display like this: (P is present, NP is not present)
[image]

I tried to retrieve the data but I get duplicate user names and it is hard to display that way. I want to use a simple way. Im using aspx site, so for example a simple table soultion would be enought.

These are my database table: USER table

[image]

DATE table

[image]

CONNECTION table

[image]

Comment: Pivoting your data like that is, honestly, something for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. Store the data in a normalised format (like your images imply you are doing) and then have the application convert the normalised dataset into a pivot table.

Comment: And how can i pivot it like that?

Comment: You don't pivot that data. You only need the employees, and then a child table row for each day of attendances. There is no need for some junction table - it only complicates this issue. See my working code below.  I typed out that code for this post - and it actually works! - so it not a lot of code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need that table that lists out the month. I find that for booking systems, or whatever? All so often the developer cooks up a table of records to represent the month.

Don't do that. If a booking is from 10 am to 11:30 am, then add a booking records (don't add a tempalte table of reocrds for those slots).

If you do that, then you are forever writing a boatload of code to create that month of reocrds, and it not at all required.

You have

People/staff   - a table of staff

Attendance  - a table, People_ID and date and true/false for attend.

That is ALL you need.

Build the month UI with code, and then simply add, or remove child records to that one given person.

So, your two data tables are this:

[image]

Ok, so now lets build a UI that:

displays the data, and ALSO lets you check off/pick which days for attendance.

We could use a Gridview, but listview tends to be MUCH better.

So, our lisview will look like this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="LV1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >

            <ItemTemplate>                    
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td><asp:Label ID="FirstnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C1" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C2" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C3" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C4" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C5" runat="server" /></td>
                      all the way to c31
                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="C31" runat="server" /></td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" class="table"  >
                    <tr runat="server" id="headerrow" style="">
                        <th runat="server">Firstname</th>
                        <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                        <th runat="server" id="H1">1</th>
                        <th runat="server" id="H2">2</th>
                        <th runat="server" id="H3">3</th>
                        <th runat="server" id="H4">4</th>
                        <th runat="server" id="H5">5</th>
                           all the way to 31
                        <th runat="server" id="H31">31</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Edits" CssClass="btn" />
```

Ok, now our code to load becomes quite simple.

The code to load the list view is this:

```
Dim dtStart As Date
Dim dtEnd As Date
Dim Days As Integer
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(DateTime.Now), Month(DateTime.Now), 1)
    Days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year(dtStart), Month(dtStart))
    dtEnd = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, Days - 1, dtStart)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY FirstName"

    Dim rstData As DataTable = Myrst(strSQL)
    LV1.DataSource = rstData
    LV1.DataBind()

    ' add day of week to the header
    Dim dPtr As Date = dtStart

    ' add day of week to header

    Dim MyHeader As HtmlTableRow = LV1.FindControl("headerrow")
    For i = 1 To Days
        Dim mytdH As HtmlTableCell = MyHeader.FindControl("H" & i)
        Dim sDay As String = dPtr.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
        mytdH.InnerHtml += "<br/>" + sDay
        dPtr = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dPtr)
    Next


End Sub
```

And we now see this:

[image]

So, all we have to do is wire up the on data row bound, and that code looks like this:

(I added the shading for weekends)

```
Protected Sub LV1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles LV1.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        ' format and load one row
        Dim gRow As ListViewItem = e.Item

        Dim PeoplePK As Integer = LV1.DataKeys(gRow.DataItemIndex).Item("ID")
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT * FROM Attendance
            WHERE People_ID = @ID
            AND ADate >= @dtStart AND ADate <= @dtEnd"

        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PeoplePK
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStart
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtEnd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtEnd

        Dim rstAttend As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

        Dim dPtr As Date = dtStart
        For i = 1 To 31

            Dim ck As CheckBox = gRow.FindControl("C" + i.ToString)
            Dim mytd As HtmlTableCell = ck.Parent

            If i <= Days Then
                If Weekday(dPtr) = 1 Or Weekday(dPtr) = 7 Then
                    ' week end - shade as blue
                    mytd.Style.Add("background-Color", "aliceblue")
                End If

                ' check for record
                Dim sFind As String = "ADate = '" & dPtr & "'"
                Dim dView As DataRow() = rstAttend.Select(sFind)
                If dView.Length > 0 Then
                    ck.Checked = dView(0).Item("Present")
                End If


            Else
                ' out of bounds for this month - hide
                mytd.Style.Add("display", "none")
                ' hide the header row also
                Dim MyHeader As HtmlTableRow = LV1.FindControl("headerrow")
                Dim mytdH As HtmlTableCell = MyHeader.FindControl("H" & i)
                mytdH.Style.Add("display", "none")
            End If
            'mytd.Style.Add("text-align", "center")
            'ck.Style.Add("background-Color", "aliceblue")

            dPtr = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dPtr)

        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

So, now you can click away on the check boxes.

the save button to save all the edits/changes is thus this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    For Each gRow As ListViewItem In LV1.Items
        Dim PeoplePK As Integer = LV1.DataKeys(gRow.DisplayIndex).Item("ID")
        Dim rstAttend As New DataTable
        rstAttend = Myrst("SELECT * FROM Attendance WHERE People_ID = " & PeoplePK)

        ' Update the data
        Dim dPtr As Date = dtStart
        For i = 1 To Days

            Dim ck As CheckBox = gRow.FindControl("C" + i.ToString)
            Dim sFind As String = "ADate = '" & dPtr & "'"
            Dim dView As DataRow() = rstAttend.Select(sFind)

            If dView.Length > 0 Then
                dView(0).Item("Present") = ck.Checked
                ' you could optonal delete records if un-checked - your choice
                '    If ck.Checked = False Then
                '        dView(0).Delete()
                '    End If
            Else
                If ck.Checked Then
                    ' we have to add this record
                    Dim NewRow As DataRow = rstAttend.NewRow
                    NewRow("People_ID") = PeoplePK
                    NewRow("ADate") = dPtr
                    NewRow("Present") = True
                    rstAttend.Rows.Add(NewRow)
                End If
            End If
            dPtr = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dPtr)
        Next
        ' save this one employee
        MyRstSave(rstAttend, "Attendance")
    Next

End Sub
```

So above works just fine. it not really a "huge" amount of code, and we thus get both display and edit.

I'm sure after you hit save, we jump to some other page to select another month or whatever, but the above quite much works rather well.

I also used 3 helper routines (but, I use these for most of my projects).

they are to get/return data as a table, and write the table back to database.

They are these 3

```
Public Function Myrst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, mycon)
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function

Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Sub MyRstSave(rstData As DataTable, strTable As String)

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Now I used check boxes, but it would be trivial to use a label or even a text box and show P or NP.

## Edit: User wants N or NP for display, not check box

Ok, so just do a search/replace on Checkbox to a label then right?

I mean, the meat and potatos here is the above layout and approach to the "problem", and things like changing a checkbox to a label is rather trivial. (changing a checkbox to a label is not much of a issue or problem - in fact, if that is too much of a challenge, then I think we have VAST MORE of a issue here!!!).

So, just change in my example markup to a label.

eg:

```
<td><asp:Label ID="C1" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="C2" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="C3" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="C4" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="C5" runat="server" /></td>
... all the way to 31
```

(as noted, we can use a search/replace on this).

Now, our code can be changed to use a label in place of a check box.

So, our code is still really the same, but now we use a label in place of a check box, so like this:

```
' check for record
Dim sFind As String = "ADate = '" & dPtr & "'"
Dim dView As DataRow() = rstAttend.Select(sFind)
If dView.Length > 0 Then
    ck.Text = IIf(dView(0).Item("Present"), "P", "NP")
Else
    ck.Text = "NP"
End If
```

And thus we now see/get this:

[image]

I'm not a whole lot sure why changing a check box to a label is all that of a difficult challenge here, but without question the above code solution is rather nice, and the cherry on top was me posting that save code.

But, just change the checkbox to a label, and tweak the code to use a label in place of check box, and you should be off to the races.

of course, one could play with formatting a bit, and change things.

so, say we add table bordered to the style class like this:

```
<table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
  border="0" class="table table-bordered"  >
```

And now we get this:

[image]

And we probably should center the text, but regardless, one thing at a time, right?

Comment: We try and keep this in public, and thus EVERYONE here benefits. If we just go one on one, then that is just make work for me, but WORSE is everyone else here does not benefit. Imagine if I decided to go one on one for someone else - YOU would not have received this answer, and no one else would benefit!  This is not a free development service, but a community of people based on acts of charity. If we were to all go one on one, then you would not even have received this answer and this whole community would fall apart. Answers here in public benefits everyone in the community - not just you

Comment: If you have a reasonable question that does not result in me having to take too much time away from my family and other tasks, then just ask here in the comments.  The posted code is working code, and it not only displays the data, but checking on boxes also saves the data back to the database for you. You really will not get more than what was posted above in a simple Q + A, but if you have any follow up question(s), do ask in public and in the comments here (so everyone else can benfit).

Comment: And how to modify, if I want to list the status (p or np) not the checkbox. I will have another input field for modifying the status

Comment: Just change the checkbox to a label. (can use search + replace). I mean, changing a check box to a label is not going to be that difficult, is it? Anyway, see my edit, I simple changed the CheckBox to a label, and then changed the 2 lines of code to use a label and text in place of the check box.